# Troubleshoot DPC++ targeting GPU with and without CUDA

Tags: nvidia, dpc++

I followed the instructions at the below website to test DPC++ on my computer.

https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/GetStartedGuide.md#build-dpc-toolchain

```
$ ./simple-sycle-app.exe
The results are correct!
```

I then modified line 23 to target my gpu

```
// Creating SYCL queue
sycl::queue Queue( sycl::gpu_selector{} );

[18:49]ec2-user$ ./simple-sycl-app-gpu.exe
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::sycl::runtime_error' what():  No device of requested type available. -1 (PI_ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) Aborted (core dumped)
```

did i need to build my dpc environment with CUDA enabled to access my K80 Nvidia GPU? I didn't enable it because CUDA support is apparently still experimental. I thought the whole point of using DPC++ was for me not to need to use CUDA. Should i be able to use my Nvidia gpu with just an nvidia driver and not CUDA?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build *llvm* compiler with CUDA support. Brief instruction is to

1. install CUDA development kit, e.g. from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-7-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=11&target_type=runfile_local)
2. Build and install Intel's llvm compiler from sources: https://github.com/intel/llvm passing `--cuda` param to configure command (see instructions on project's README)
3. use compiler according to [this instruction](https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/GetStartedGuide.md#use-dpc-toolchain), e.g. like this:

   ```
   export DPCPP_HOME=~/sycl_workspace
   export PATH=$DPCPP_HOME/llvm/build/bin:$PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DPCPP_HOME/llvm/build/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   clang++ -fsycl -fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda \
    simple-sycl-app.cpp -o simple-sycl-app-cuda.exe
   ```